# Weak correlation even with y-training set inside x-training set in SKlearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

We are using Python + SK-Learn with the MLPClassifier. We are getting relative bad results. As a sanity check we tried to add the y-desired output to the x-input set. In this case you would expect to have 100% score. But that's not the case, the score is pretty low (20%) which is much better than random guessing but still really bad. We have around 150 inputs (most of them are booleans) and 1 output which is an integer between 1 and 1500. When we divide the numbers to around 5 categories (integers between 0 and 4) the score is around 96%.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import cPickle
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error


scaler = StandardScaler()
xset = np.genfromtxt('xkey.csv', delimiter=",")
yset = np.genfromtxt('ykey.csv', delimiter=",")
# yset = np.rint((5-1)*(yset)/np.max(yset))
print "Number of categories: " + str(np.max(yset)+1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xset, yset, test_size=0.10)
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

clf = MLPClassifier(algorithm='adam', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(100,20))
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

score = clf.score(X_test,y_test)
print ("score: "+str(score))

ypredicted = clf.predict(X_test)
sqerr = mean_squared_error(ypredicted, y_test)
err = mean_absolute_error(ypredicted, y_test)

print ("err: " + str(err))
print ("sqerr: " + str(sqerr))
```

Comment: Please explain what your y-training set and x-training set are. Is your y-training set is indeed your "target" for the x-training set? It appears that you are mixing up the concept of the dataset and the target.

Comment: By x-training set i mean the input object and by y-training set i mean the desired output value.

Comment: is there any relation between these 1500 numbers? Is "2" more similar to "3" than to "1200"?

Comment: Yes! that's kind of ranking.

Comment: Note that this is a classifier. How many different "classes" do you have? (i.e. how many different rankings between 0 and 1500? Are there enough training data per "class" for your classifier to work properly? If every training instance is ranked differently then perhaps you shouldn't try classification, but regression, so you have to use `MLPRegressor`.

Comment: Thanks dkar it really helped me!